# Two websites for one photography business

Tags: seo, multiple-domains, local-seo

I have a new SEO client who has currently split their business across three websites, I advised they should merge into a single site, but they are insisting on retaining 2 sites:

- 1 x specialist wedding photography - newer sites, GMB listing set up and visible
- 1 x various types of photography, site also translated in Japanese. Much older site and generates many leads through organic search and referral.

The sites currently have the following information relating to the business owner:

- Same contact name on each site
- Same phone number
- Same ABN (Australian Business Number)
- Unique email
- Street address only on the wedding photography site

Can I retain the two websites and optimise the Wedding photography site (with the active GMB listing) without it being damaged by the existence of the second site (which will only be optimised for organic SEO)

What steps can I take? Such as remove ABN from second photography site, use different phone number. Keep as organic SEO without address.

Or is this really inadvisable, should it be handled as a single business one address, or as multiple businesses of same owner at multiple addresses?

**Update:**

I have been advised by Google (GMB Support) not to have two businesses offering the same service at the same address owned by the same owner

Comment: It might be best if you added your update as an answer below, along with some details (e.g., copying part of an email received), which you can select as the answer to let others know and earn more rep.

Comment: @dan that was some time ago over the phone

Answer (score 3):

It is quite common for a single business entity to have multiple websites. In your example having one website focused on the wedding photography and having the other dedicated to other generic photography will be fine as long as substantial content is unique and relevant to the specific focus of the site.

As for removing addresses or abn numbers these are not considered substantial content and as such can be the same across the two sites.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple websites is fine and actually sometimes used as an SEO strategy. Listing the same address and phone number shouldn't be an issue but avoid any other duplicate content.

If you're interested in reading more you can google 'Hub and Spoke seo'